# How do I ALLOW apostrophe in htaccess RewriteRule regex?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm retrieving menus from database and some of them have an apostrophe - ' - in their names.
In a part of my code I have to compare the name from the database with the url, but it fails when the url has an apostrophe.

For example:

when I get the name from the db I get it as it is: `foo's`

but from the url, even if the url is `web.com?menu=foo's` when I do this:

```
$menu = urldecode($_GET['menu']);
```

I get only `foo`

this is my htaccess Rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^explore/([0-9a-zA-Z\ ]+) renderpage.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

I've tried all the possible combination in my php, it's not that, it is this RewriteRule that doesn't allow apostrophe, I've also tried `([0-9a-zA-Z\ ']+)` in my regex and `([0-9a-zA-Z\ \']+)` but to no avail.

Comment: did you just try this regex `RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)`

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep, with this regex it shows me like this foo\'s

Comment: but it's fine I'll do a str_replace, it's good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the position of apostrophe Try this:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z'\]+)
```

or

```
([0-9a-zA-Z']+)
```

Comment: this works too, but it shows like this: foo\'s . But it's good enough I'll do a str_replace

Comment: It was because I had to allow Space also, but I have to put it before the Space